# OIM 12.2.1.3.0: How to hide a catalogue item (Application instance/Roles) for specific set of users or end users

Tags: oim

I have tried using Expression Language #{oimcontext.currentUser.roles['SYSTEM ADMINISTRATORS'] != null} from web composer but it doesn't allow me to hide any specific catalog item. It rather hides all the catalog items.

Steps: created sandbox->Request for self-> Customize -> Structure -> Navigate to appInstance which needs to be hidden -> click edit in web composer -> Under Display Option Tab -> Added EL #{oimcontext.currentUser.roles['SYSTEM ADMINISTRATORS'] != null} -> apply ok.

I've also tried changing the ORG in application instance and defining IS_REQUESTABLE=0. But they didn't seem to help.

Can somebody help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the "is_requestable" attribute for the entity (or entities) you want to hide. For example, the following query hides all entitlements for a certain application instance:

```
update catalog set is_requestable = 1 where parent_ entity _key = <key> and parent_entity_type = 'ApplicationInstance';
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to manage visibility of the catalog is by separating out the groups of users by Organization and only publishing to the Org what you want them to view.